# Should interaction term in linear mixed model be different from separate standard regressions?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, interaction, continuous-data

I'm getting very different results when looking at the slopes from standard linear regressions and a linear mixed model and it would be great to see if I'm going wrong somewhere! I have a set of measures over time in different locations. I first ran standard linear regressions separately for each location, `lm(y ~ year)` and stored the regression slopes. The slopes are my measure of interest, and these turn out to be associated with a location-level continuous variable, access to drugs:
[image: simple linear regression slopes]

However, I'm aware it's probably not ideal to run separate regressions for each location. So I analysed the data from all locations together in a linear mixed model, allowing for random slopes and intercepts by location and testing for an interaction of year with the continuous 'drugs' variable.

```
re.lm1 <- lmer(y ~ year + (1+year|location)  + drugs + drugs*year, 
           data = test, REML = F)
```

The interaction term drugs*year is now close to zero (-0.001293) in this model:

```
summary(re.lm1)

Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood t-tests use Satterthwaite 
approximations to degrees of  freedom [lmerMod]

 AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid
 143.6    161.5    -63.8    127.6       61 


Scaled residuals: 
 Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.05646 -0.55097  0.06747  0.63842  2.33078 

Random effects:
Groups    Name                       Variance  Std.Dev. Corr 
location (Intercept)                 4.215e-01 0.649221    
year                                 5.172e-05 0.007191 -1.00
Residual                             3.878e+00 1.969294      

Number of obs: 69, groups:  location, 8

Fixed effects:
                             Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)

(Intercept)                  0.256095   0.460052  6.827000   0.557    0.596    
year                        -0.228865   0.034820 16.129000  -6.573 6.16e-06 ***
drugs                        0.028993   0.017318 11.213000   1.674    0.122   
 year:drugs                  -0.001293   0.001483 16.299000  -0.872    0.396   

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
        (Intr)  year   drugs
year        -0.593              
drugs       -0.790  0.630       
year*drug    0.539 -0.832 -0.800
```

Is the lmer model correctly specified? Is it problematic to have an interaction with a continuous variable? I appreciate the mixed model will weight each location a little differently compared with standard lm, and shrink the regression slopes, but would you expect such a large difference in results?

On further inspection, several of the fitted regression slopes for each site in the linear mixed model are pretty different from those estimated from standard linear regression (i.e. shrunk towards the population mean). My concern is that they do not actually fit the original data well at all. Which method is better, when you are specifically interested in the slopes? Do I actually want to shrink towards the population mean?

Here's my data:

```
test <- structure(list(location = c(33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 
33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 
33, 33, 40, 40, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 
48, 48, 48, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 
51, 51, 51, 52, 52, 52, 53, 53, 53, 54, 54, 54, 54), y = c(0.327350413631667, 
-2.2780409557499e-05, 0.0285732524915742, 0.906285256814651, 
-0.195932692649336, 0.0855776774661171, 0.112822458332082, -0.488556708846771, 
0.923090074202585, 0.0875464976249184, 0.125163142954006, -0.584513339557151, 
-0.364643113587907, -0.269663566949101, 0.679557434434071, 0.455634284801165, 
-3.2188758248682, -1.53180376437479, -1.59426530460129, -1.45913001910082, 
-1.53219246045027, -1.51634748936809, -3.45095350667561, -1.70210681231946, 
-1.8860189125158, -2.32134787979667, -1.94365960387801, -2.31156068595034, 
-1.89674410871378, -0.602479248108237, -0.0408219945202549, -0.795712342923794, 
-1.83654493551693, -2.28715345684574, -2.19793780784455, -2.1930990894485, 
1.28401878353162, 1.65066602994786, 0.934243425756902, 0.439878238221924, 
0.852446981066467, 0.415507039549398, 0.439883139567324, -0.117783035656382, 
0.505410333584185, 0.543362973357692, 0.504514938261331, 0.379747433833854, 
1.03630487094228, -0.126333285897603, -0.872405149843068, 0.530882723295065, 
0.20727124915536, -0.890833179061281, 0.225112917644441, -1.18223729391345, 
-0.844312981682532, -0.719136634871002, -1.24696572940378, -1.54162061367905, 
-0.308092193751835, -1.52921949551098, -1.90392328473074, -0.265168408349729, 
-1.59963964101079, -1.81246311615359, 1.07123158869382, 1.27943121557753, 
1.61854610954946, -2.15308831060533), year = c(1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 
1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 4.5, 4.5, 
4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 6.5, 7.5, 7.5, 8.5, 8.5, 9.5, 9.5, 10.5, 5.5, 
10.5, 0.5, 0.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 6.5, 7.5, 0.5, 1, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 
5.5, 6.5, 7, 1, 1.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 7.5, 7.5, 
8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 9.5, 11.5, 8.5, 9.5, 11.5, 8.5, 9.5, 11.5, 0.5, 
2.5, 4, 10.5), drugs = c(7.52, 7.52, 7.52, 7.52, 7.52, 7.52, 
7.52, 7.52, 7.52, 7.52, 7.52, 7.52, 7.52, 7.52, 7.52, 7.52, 7.52, 
7.52, 7.52, 7.52, 7.52, 7.52, 7.52, 7.52, 7.52, 7.52, 7.52, 8.13333333333333, 
8.13333333333333, 11.6375, 11.6375, 11.6375, 11.6375, 11.6375, 
11.6375, 11.6375, 11.6375, 11.6375, 11.6375, 11.6375, 11.6375, 
11.6375, 11.6375, 11.6375, 33.7, 33.7, 33.7, 33.7, 33.7, 33.7, 
33.7, 33.7, 33.7, 33.7, 33.7, 33.7, 33.7, 33.7, 33.7, 33.7, 64.25, 
64.25, 64.25, 64.25, 64.25, 64.25, 27.3090909090909, 27.3090909090909, 
27.3090909090909, 27.3090909090909)), .Names = c("location", 
"y", "year", "drugs"), row.names = c("164", "165", "166", "167", 
"168", "169", "170", "171", "184", "185", "222", "223", "224", 
"225", "240", "241", "243", "259", "282", "285", "313", "315", 
"328", "330", "349", "350", "376", "290", "382", "139", "140", 
"196", "230", "250", "295", "318", "141", "145", "197", "231", 
"251", "267", "296", "304", "146", "176", "232", "252", "269", 
"271", "298", "299", "300", "322", "323", "335", "336", "339", 
"359", "385", "337", "357", "383", "338", "358", "384", "143", 
"198", "234", "379"), class = "data.frame")
```